# Меню на MySQL. Есть ли дочерние элементы?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Табличка menu содержит поля: name, url, parent (название, куда переходить и родительский пункт меню)...

Как определить, что пункт содержит дочерние элементы?

Comment: Нужно именно на `mysql`? Могу поделиться, как я на php делаю древовидные массивы.

Comment: Структура меню лежит в базе... Нужно просто взять оттуда и отобразить...

Answer (score 1):

`select id from таблица where parent=айдишник`

Или для нескольких пунктов сразу: `select parent, id from menutable where parent in (айдишник, ещё-айдишник, итд)`

Answer (score 1):

`if exists (select 1 from menu where id='номер пункта' and ifnull(parent,0) != 0)`

`then select 1`
`endif`

если  вернет 1 значит есть

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM menu WHERE `parent` = NULL");
$parent = $parent->fetch_all();
foreach ($parent as $item){
  $check = $mysqli->query("select * from menu where `parent`='{$item[0]}'");
  $num = $check->num_rows;
  echo "{$num} елемент(-ов)\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно же, найти элементы, у которых parent = id текущего

```
select level_1.id, level_1.name, level_1.url, level_1.parent, count(level_2.id)
from menu level_1
left join menu level_2 on level_2.parent = level_1.id
group by level_1.id, level_1.name, level_1.url, level_1.parent
```

или сабселектом

```
select *,
  (select count(*) from menu level_2 where level_2.parent = level_1.id)
from menu level_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, нужно получить именно структуру меню, а не просто пункты, у которых есть родители. Предлагаю вариант решения с помощью `php`. Сначала чиатем всё меню из БД в массив (индексы массива - это индекс `id`)

```
$data = array(
    '5' => array(
               'name' => 'куку',
               'url'  => 'cucu',
               'parent' => null
           ),
    '7' => array(
               'name' => '333',
               'url'  => '444',
               'parent' => 5
           )
);
```

После чего пробегаем по массиву, и все дочерние элементы вкладываем в родительские:

```
foreach ($data as $id => $row)
    if ($parent = $row['parent']) {
        $data[$parent]['child'][$id] = &$row;
    } else {
        $tree[$id] = &$row;
    }
}
```

Получаем массив вида:

```
$tree = array(
    '5' => array(
               'name'   => 'куку',
               'url'    => 'cucu',
               'parent' => null
               'child'  => array(
                               '7' => array(
                                          'name' => '333',
                                          'url'  => '444',
                                          'parent' => 5
                                      )
                           )
           )
);
```